# Stop a context menu being closed on background click / back

Tags: android, android-contextmenu

I can show a context menu this is great.

Now I don't want the user to be able to close the context menu without choosing an option how would I go about doing this?
Or should I stop being lazy and move to a dialog?

Comment: Please allow the user to gracefully exit when they accidentally bring up this menu/dialog, such as by pressing the BACK button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public API to control back-key behavior on context menu.
As you suggested your best option is to move to dialogs.